# Laravel - Copy collection data to another table and delete

Tags: php, laravel

I want to delete entries which are older than 3 days and move them to another (archive) table.

So far I do it like this:

```
public function handle() {
    $route = Route::where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subDays(3))->get();
    $routeCopy = $route;
    $route = Route::where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subDays(3))->delete();

    foreach ($routeCopy as $r) {
        $routeArchive = new RouteArchive();
        $routeArchive->id = $r->id;
        $routeArchive->startLocation = $r->startLocation;
        $routeArchive->endLocation = $r->endLocation;
        $routeArchive->save();
    }

}
```

Is there a way to avoid double querying in this case?
Btw `Route` and `RouteArchive` are not same. `Route` contains many other columns including `id, startLocation, endLocation`... `RouteArchive` contains only `id, startLocation` and `endLocation`.

Comment: You can not make a delete without querying the database again. The first one is a SELECT statement and the second one is DELETE FROM statement.

Comment: I found another stack overflow entry on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120305/laravel-delete-whole-collection

Comment: Would [Soft Deleting](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#soft-deleting) be out of the question for this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a primary key set up on the route table, you should be able to do something like this

```
public function handle() {
    $route = Route::where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subDays(3))->get();
//    $routes = $route;
 //   $route = Route::where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subDays(3))->delete();

    foreach ($route as $r) {
        $routeArchive = new RouteArchive();
        $routeArchive->id = $r->id;
        $routeArchive->startLocation = $r->startLocation;
        $routeArchive->endLocation = $r->endLocation;
        $routeArchive->save();

        $r->delete();
    }

}
```